# array so exibe o primeiro length usando foreach

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo exibir um array dentro de uma lista mas quando executo a função so exibe o primeiro numero do array

```
let lista = document.getElementById("lista");
  par.forEach(()=>{
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    for(i = 0; i < par.length; i++){
      item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(par[i]));
      return lista.appendChild(item)
    }
  });
```

No HTML sai assim

```
2
2
2
2
```

no console

```
par
(4) [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há um sério problema de entendimento no seu código, já que você está aninhando, de forma desnecessária, um `for` dentro de um `forEach`.

O [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) invocará o *callback* passado para cada membro do *array*, o que fará com que o seu `for` seja *criado* quatro vezes, sempre com o índice zero.

Você deverá usar um ou outro. Com o `for`:

```js
const lista = document.getElementById('lista');
const par = [2, 4, 6, 8];

for (let i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(par[i]));
  lista.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

Se você quiser usar o `for` e o ambiente suportar, pode também optar pelo [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Ou com um `forEach`:

```js
const lista = document.getElementById('lista');
const par = [2, 4, 6, 8];

par.forEach((elemento) => {
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(elemento));
  lista.appendChild(item);
});
```

```html
<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

Comment: Me tira uma duvida sobre o forEach. Eu não entendi direito a parte que ele entende que o **elemento** vai ser o Length do par, ao botar o (elemento) ele automaticamente entende que estou falando do par[length]

Comment: O `forEach` irá invocar o _callback_ que você o passou para cada iteração, passando os elementos e outros dados como parâmetro. Desse modo, dentro do _callback_, você poderá acessar os parâmetros correspondentes ao elemento e índice da iteração atual, bem como o array (em ordem de parâmetro 1, 2 e 3). Para saber mais, consulte a [documentação do `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) que eu linkei.